# php mysql query condition oop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, conditional-statements

I was wondering how I could make a general function for SELECT mysql queries from my SelectQuery object in PHP. SelectQuery extends Query, which means it inherits the database connection, a realescape method (which is mysqli_real_escape_string()), and a query method which executes the query. Besides that, it also gets a protected variable called _sql, which is the SQL the query() method passes to the database. And it also gets a protected variable called _table, which contains the (escaped) name of the table it's working on.

My code:

```
public function select($columns = array('*'), $known = null, $limit = null, $offset = null, $orderby = null, $asc = true) {
    if (!is_array($columns)) {
        new Error('Parameter is not an array.');
        return;
    }

    $select = '';
    foreach($columns as $column) {
        $select .= (($select != '')?', ':'') . '`' . $this->realescape($column) . '`';
    }
    $conditions = '';
    if (is_array($known)) {
        foreach($known as $column => $value) {
            $conditions .= (($conditions != '')?' AND ':'WHERE ') . '`' . $this->realescape($column) . '` = ' . ((is_string($value))?'\'':'') . $this->realescape($value) . ((is_string($value))?'\'':'');
        }
    }
    $domain = '';
    if ($limit !== null) {
        $domain = 'LIMIT ' . $this->realescape($limit);
        if ($offset !== null) {
            $domain .= ' OFFSET = ' . $this->realescape($offset);
        }
    }
    $order = '';
    if ($orderby !== null) {
        $order = 'ORDER BY `' . $this->realescape($orderby) . '` ' . (($asc)?'ASC':'DESC');
    }

    $this->_sql = 'SELECT ' . $select . ' FROM `' . $this->_table . '`';
    if ($conditions != '') {
        $this->_sql .= ' ' . $conditions;
    }
    if ($domain != '') {
        $this->_sql .= ' ' . $domain;
    }
    if ($order != '') {
        $this->_sql .= ' ' . $order;
    }
    return $this->query();
}
```

The $known variable might be set, if set it should be an array which contains all the 'known' elements of the rows we are selecting.

My question: How can I make this so that conditions such as
`age < 18`, or `date > 5120740154` are easily made?

Also, if you think the way I'm making this work is wrong, please say so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a method for selects in my custom DB class because, as your code shows, you usually end up writing just as much in a function call as you would writing out the whole query.  I also don't need to worry about more complex things like the conditions you mention.

Comment: @G-Nugget: Hmm, thank you for sharing that, I might change it to a more simple way of executing queries.. The only problem I see is escaping, since MySQLi needs a database connection identifier to escape (I'm not sure why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamically build WHERE conditions that can use any operators

Create a $where array that holds your where conditions.

```
$where = array (
    'age <' => 18,
    'date >' => 5120740154
);
```

You can build that into your SQL query using a function like this:

```
private function buildWhereConditions($where) {
    $conditions = 'WHERE 1=1';
    /*1=1 is just so you can easily append ANDs */
    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
        $conditions .= " AND $key $value ";
    } 
    return $conditions;
}
```

This will return the where conditions to be appended to your query:

```
WHERE 1=1 AND age < 18 AND date > 5120740154
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'm not a big fan of the WHERE 1=1 thing, but the other part is fine.. The only thing bothering me about it, is that I have to include the operator(?) in the column-name. How can I do this differently? Maybe create condition-objects so it can contain 3 values instead of 2 (key=>value)?

Comment: You can get away from 1=1 using your ternary operator: ($conditions != '')?' AND ':'WHERE '
Why is it a problem to include the operator in the column name?  Apart from it being a little ugly, it works.
You COULD create an object that contains 3 values, but its a hassle.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.